# Does implicit typying exist in Apex?

Tags: types, salesforce, apex

Many modern statically-typed languages provide the ability to write variables without explicitly providing the type.

For example, C# uses `var`:

`var foo = new Bar();`

`var foo2 = "blah blah";`

Does this functionality exist in Apex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not. Apex has strong, static, explicit typing, and provides no support for type inference or implicit typing.